# Can't run tests on angular sample project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular-material

I've cloned [Angular Material-Start](https://github.com/angular/material-start) project. As documentation says:

> run `npm run tests` to start all your Karma unit tests.
>   But this conmmand gives me an error:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\DevSoft\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Taras\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "tests"
npm ERR! node v5.7.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.9

npm ERR! missing script: tests
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

What do I do wrong? How can I run the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `tests` script in the package.json file:

https://github.com/angular/material-start/blob/master/package.json

The tests have been disabled:

https://github.com/angular/material-start/commit/3a525fe89581c5b945388c1714ca3e4b64027d1e